# Linear operator norm when symmetric

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products, alternative-proof, symmetric-matrices

We define the norm of an operator $A:X \to Y$, with $X$ a pre Hilbert space, as $$ \lVert A \lVert := \sup\{\lVert Ax \lVert \text{ for } x \in X, \lVert x \rVert \leq 1 \}  $$

When $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $Ax.y=x.Ay$, then we have that $$\lVert A \lVert = \sup\{\lvert Ax.x\rvert \text{ for } x \in X, \lVert x \rVert \leq 1 \}=:M $$

The proof I was given easily shows that $M \leq \lVert A \lVert$. But to show that $M \geq \lVert A \lVert$, it uses polarization formulas of the inner product and uses a vector $v:= \frac {Ax}{b}$ out of nowhere and then finds the right $b$ so that everything works.

I was wondering if someone has another proof to show that $M \geq \lVert A \lVert$.

Comment: There are other ways but they require more advanced tools. The polar identity is very natural. It suffices to represent the real part of the inner product and consider just two terms. I do not remember any vector out of nowhere in such a proof.